# Running only specific methods in test suite using Junit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit5, test-suite, junit-jupiter

I have 2 test classes (A,B), both have 3 test methods. I put them into a test suite and want to run only specific methods (example: only the first method in all classes).
For this use case in junit4 I had custom runner and this was done by passing the Runner into @RunWith(CustomRunner.class).

I am trying to migrate my junit4 test suites into junit5 test suites. I have created a test suite:

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@SelectClasses({com.example.junit5testexample.A.class,
com.example.junit5testexample.B.class})
@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("junit5 suite")
public class JUnit5TestSuiteExample {

}
```

How can I now filter the methods? Should I use Extensions and @ExtendWith? If so, which extension would you recommend?

Comment: What about tagging the methods and then using https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/IncludeTags.html. I don’t see how Jupiter extensions could help you.

Comment: Sadly tagging methods is not an option as the methods will be chosen in runtime. Tried with providing custom class implementing ExecutionCondition(''An ExecutionCondition is evaluated to determine if a given container or test should be executed based on the supplied ExtensionContext. '') however this does not work.

Comment: For that scenario using the suite-engine is probably not a workable approach. You could argue it's missing the select method feature - which I think it does. You can open an issue to add it, but that won't help you in the short run.

Comment: Thanks for information. What do you think about creating a custom TestEngine? Is it possible to filter by method names in discover method?

Comment: That would require to duplicate most of what the suite engine does. But yes, I think it’s possible. It’s probably easier to fork and patch the suite engine - and then offer the feature as a PR to the JUnit Team.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar requirement and it took me quite a while to find the right way to do this.

If still relevant for you or someone else stumbling over this: Have a look at `PostDiscoveryFilter`. Custom filters can be added (at least in recent JUnit5 versions), to filter the originally-discovered tests further down by custom code, especially if such filters can only be defined at runtime.

Sample snippet:

```java
public class MyFilter implements PostDiscoveryFilter {
  @Override
  public FilterResult apply(TestDescriptor td) {
    if (td instanceof MethodBasedTestDescriptor mbtd) {
      // covers normal and templated test-methods (e.g. @ParameterizedTest)
      if (mbtd.getTestMethod().getName().contains("IDontLikeYourName")) {
        return FilterResult.excluded("excluded");
      }
    }
    return FilterResult.included("included");
  }
}
```

The excluded tests will be excluded and won't be part of the executed TestPlan.

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1997
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-post-discovery-filters-custom

Comment: Thanks! Using a filter in the way that is described in this answer allowed me to filter the tests that were pulled in via the suite class.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with providing custom class implementing ExecutionCondition however this does not work and I am not sure why. Am I missing something or is the whole approach wrong?

```
public class RunMethodCondition implements ExecutionCondition { 

    @Override 
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context){
        final Method testedMethod = context.getTestMethod().get();
        if(testedMethod.getName()=="Atest1"){
            return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("enabled");
        }
        return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("disabled");
    }

}
```

and my test suite:

```
@SelectClasses({com.example.junit5testexample.A.class,
com.example.junit5testexample.B.class})
@Suite
@ExtendWith(RunMethodCondition.class)
public class JUnit5TestSuiteExample {

}
```

From junit docs: "An ExecutionCondition is evaluated to determine if a given container or test should be executed based on the supplied ExtensionContext."

Comment: This approach does not work because a Jupiter extension from the suite class will NOT be propagated from the suite engine to the included test classes. The suite engine does not care about anything Jupiter-related. What it does is call the JUnit 5 platform API for discovering and running tests.